# RULE planner does not support calling procedures (when using apoc.do.when)

Tags: csv, neo4j, load, cypher, neo4j-apoc

Related to That previous question [How to make the Cypher request to handle those both cases without duplicating Nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50497811/how-to-make-the-cypher-request-to-handle-those-both-cases-without-duplicating-no)

I tried to solve this using apoc.do.when but I got this Error

I don't know how to solve this.

**Neo.DatabaseError.Statement.ExecutionFailed RULE planner does not support calling procedures**

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///the-file-name.csv" as 
line FIELDTERMINATOR ','  
OPTIONAL MATCH (n:Region) 
WHERE  n.region contains "BLANKEMPTYVIDE" AND n.identifier= line.CODE_TER 
CALL apoc.do.when(
   n IS NULL,
  'MERGE (r:Region{region: line.TERRITOIRE}) ON CREATE SET r.description=line.TERRITOIRE ON CREATE SET r.identifier=line.CODE_TER ON CREATE SET r.id = toString(id(r)) RETURN r',
  'RETURN n AS r',
  {}) YIELD value
WITH value.r AS r,line
SET r.identifier=line.CODE_TER
SET r.description=line.TERRITOIRE
SET r.region=line.TERRITOIRE
WITH r,line
OPTIONAL MATCH (ci:City) where ci.cityName contains "BLANKEMPTYVIDE" AND ci.regionIdentifier= line.CODE_TER
CALL apoc.do.when(
   ci IS NULL,
  'MERGE (c:City {cityName:line.BRICK}) ON CREATE SET c.identifier=line.CODE_BRICK ON CREATE SET c.region=line.TERRITOIRE ON CREATE SET c.regionIdentifier=line.CODE_TER ON CREATE SET c.zip=line.CODE_BRICK ON CREATE SET c.description=line.BRICK ON CREATE SET c.id = toString(id(c)) RETURN c',
  'RETURN ci AS c',
  {}) YIELD value
WITH value.c AS c,line,r
SET c.identifier=line.CODE_BRICK 
SET c.region=line.TERRITOIRE
SET c.regionIdentifier=line.CODE_TER
SET c.zip=line.CODE_BRICK
SET c.description=line.BRICK
SET c.cityName=line.BRICK  
WITH c,r,line
MATCH (c {identifier:line.CODE_BRICK}),(r {identifier:line.CODE_TER})
CREATE UNIQUE (c)-[:IS_A_City_BELONGING_TO]->(r)
WITH c,r,line
OPTIONAL MATCH (sec:Sector) 
WHERE  sec.description contains "BLANKEMPTYVIDE" AND sec.regionIdentifier=line.CODE_TER 
CALL apoc.do.when(
   sec IS NULL,
  'MERGE (s:Sector {sectorName:line.SOUSBRICK}) ON CREATE SET s.identifier=line.CODE_SBRICK ON CREATE SET s.region=line.TERRITOIRE ON CREATE SET s.regionIdentifier=line.CODE_TER ON CREATE SET s.city=line.BRICK ON CREATE SET s.cityIdentifier=line.CODE_BRICK ON CREATE SET s.description=line.SOUSBRICK ON CREATE SET s.zip=line.SOUSBRICK ON CREATE SET s.id = toString(id(s)) RETURN s',
  'RETURN sec AS s',
  {}) YIELD value
WITH value.s AS s,line,c,r
SET s.identifier=line.CODE_SBRICK 
SET s.region=line.TERRITOIRE 
SET s.regionIdentifier=line.CODE_TER 
SET s.city=line.BRICK 
SET s.cityIdentifier=line.CODE_BRICK 
SET s.description=line.SOUSBRICK 
SET s.zip=line.SOUSBRICK 
SET s.sectorName = line.SOUSBRICK   
WITH s,c,r,line
MATCH (s {identifier:line.CODE_SBRICK}),(r{identifier:line.CODE_TER}) 
CREATE UNIQUE (s)-[:IS_A_SECTOR_BELONGING_TO_THAT_REGION]->(r) 
WITH s,c,r,line
MATCH (s {identifier:line.CODE_SBRICK}),(c{identifier:line.CODE_BRICK})
CREATE UNIQUE (s)-[:IS_A_SECTOR_BELONGING_TO_THAT_CITY]->(c)
```

**the-file-name.csv is on the previous question** [How to make the Cypher request to handle those both cases without duplicating Nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50497811/how-to-make-the-cypher-request-to-handle-those-both-cases-without-duplicating-no)

**Update with advices from cybersam**¸

```
    LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///the-file-name.csv" as 
line FIELDTERMINATOR ','  
with line as line
OPTIONAL MATCH (n:Region) 
WHERE  n.region contains "BLANKEMPTYVIDE" AND n.identifier= line.CODE_TER 
with n
CALL apoc.do.when(
   n IS NULL,
  'MERGE (r:Region{region: line.TERRITOIRE}) ON CREATE SET r.description=line.TERRITOIRE ON CREATE SET r.identifier=line.CODE_TER ON CREATE SET r.id = toString(id(r)) RETURN r',
  'RETURN n AS r',
  {}) YIELD value
WITH value.r AS r, line 
SET r.identifier=line.CODE_TER
SET r.description=line.TERRITOIRE
SET r.region=line.TERRITOIRE
WITH r,line
OPTIONAL MATCH (ci:City) where ci.cityName contains "BLANKEMPTYVIDE" AND ci.regionIdentifier= line.CODE_TER
CALL apoc.do.when(
   ci IS NULL,
  'MERGE (c:City {cityName:line.BRICK}) ON CREATE SET c.identifier=line.CODE_BRICK ON CREATE SET c.region=line.TERRITOIRE ON CREATE SET c.regionIdentifier=line.CODE_TER ON CREATE SET c.zip=line.CODE_BRICK ON CREATE SET c.description=line.BRICK ON CREATE SET c.id = toString(id(c)) RETURN c',
  'RETURN ci AS c',
  {}) YIELD value
WITH value.c AS c,line,r
SET c.identifier=line.CODE_BRICK 
SET c.region=line.TERRITOIRE
SET c.regionIdentifier=line.CODE_TER
SET c.zip=line.CODE_BRICK
SET c.description=line.BRICK
SET c.cityName=line.BRICK  
WITH c,r,line
MATCH (c {identifier:line.CODE_BRICK}),(r {identifier:line.CODE_TER})
MERGE (c)-[:IS_A_City_BELONGING_TO]->(r)
WITH c,r,line
OPTIONAL MATCH (sec:Sector) 
WHERE  sec.description contains "BLANKEMPTYVIDE" AND sec.regionIdentifier=line.CODE_TER 
CALL apoc.do.when(
   sec IS NULL,
  'MERGE (s:Sector {sectorName:line.SOUSBRICK}) ON CREATE SET s.identifier=line.CODE_SBRICK ON CREATE SET s.region=line.TERRITOIRE ON CREATE SET s.regionIdentifier=line.CODE_TER ON CREATE SET s.city=line.BRICK ON CREATE SET s.cityIdentifier=line.CODE_BRICK ON CREATE SET s.description=line.SOUSBRICK ON CREATE SET s.zip=line.SOUSBRICK ON CREATE SET s.id = toString(id(s)) RETURN s',
  'RETURN sec AS s',
  {}) YIELD value
WITH value.s AS s,line,c,r
SET s.identifier=line.CODE_SBRICK 
SET s.region=line.TERRITOIRE 
SET s.regionIdentifier=line.CODE_TER 
SET s.city=line.BRICK 
SET s.cityIdentifier=line.CODE_BRICK 
SET s.description=line.SOUSBRICK 
SET s.zip=line.SOUSBRICK 
SET s.sectorName = line.SOUSBRICK   
WITH s,c,r,line
MATCH (s {identifier:line.CODE_SBRICK}),(r{identifier:line.CODE_TER}) 
MERGE (s)-[:IS_A_SECTOR_BELONGING_TO_THAT_REGION]->(r) 
WITH s,c,r,line
MATCH (s {identifier:line.CODE_SBRICK}),(c{identifier:line.CODE_BRICK})
MERGE (s)-[:IS_A_SECTOR_BELONGING_TO_THAT_CITY]->(c)
```

**When I replace Create Unique with MERGE CLAUSE The Cypher execution fails with this error Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Variable `line` not defined (line 12, column 20 (offset: 469))
"WITH value.r AS r, line "
                    ^.**

what i am doing is as below. 1st apoc.do.when happily consumes line variable,  but 
when the cypher reach (WITH value.r AS r, line )  I got breaking code with error Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Variable line not defined

**Final update upon cybersam advice and it works fine and perfect.**

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///the-file-name.csv" as line 
FIELDTERMINATOR ','  
with line as line
OPTIONAL MATCH (n:Region) 
WHERE  n.region contains "BLANKEMPTYVIDE" AND n.identifier= line.CODE_TER 
WITH n, line
CALL apoc.do.when(
   n IS NULL,
  'MERGE (r:Region{region: line.TERRITOIRE}) ON CREATE SET r.description=line.TERRITOIRE ON CREATE SET r.identifier=line.CODE_TER ON CREATE SET r.id = toString(id(r)) RETURN r',
  'RETURN n AS r',
  {n: n, line: line}) YIELD value
WITH value.r AS r, line 
SET r.identifier=line.CODE_TER
SET r.description=line.TERRITOIRE
SET r.region=line.TERRITOIRE
WITH r,line
OPTIONAL MATCH (ci:City) where ci.cityName contains "BLANKEMPTYVIDE" AND ci.regionIdentifier= line.CODE_TER
CALL apoc.do.when(
   ci IS NULL,
  'MERGE (c:City {cityName:line.BRICK}) ON CREATE SET c.identifier=line.CODE_BRICK ON CREATE SET c.region=line.TERRITOIRE ON CREATE SET c.regionIdentifier=line.CODE_TER ON CREATE SET c.zip=line.CODE_BRICK ON CREATE SET c.description=line.BRICK ON CREATE SET c.id = toString(id(c)) RETURN c',
  'RETURN ci AS c',
  {ci: ci, line: line}) YIELD value
WITH value.c AS c,line,r
SET c.identifier=line.CODE_BRICK 
SET c.region=line.TERRITOIRE
SET c.regionIdentifier=line.CODE_TER
SET c.zip=line.CODE_BRICK
SET c.description=line.BRICK
SET c.cityName=line.BRICK  
WITH c,r,line
MATCH (c {identifier:line.CODE_BRICK}),(r {identifier:line.CODE_TER})
MERGE (c)-[:IS_A_City_BELONGING_TO]->(r)
WITH c,r,line
OPTIONAL MATCH (sec:Sector) 
WHERE  sec.description contains "BLANKEMPTYVIDE" AND sec.regionIdentifier=line.CODE_TER 
CALL apoc.do.when(
   sec IS NULL,
  'MERGE (s:Sector {sectorName:line.SOUSBRICK}) ON CREATE SET s.identifier=line.CODE_SBRICK ON CREATE SET s.region=line.TERRITOIRE ON CREATE SET s.regionIdentifier=line.CODE_TER ON CREATE SET s.city=line.BRICK ON CREATE SET s.cityIdentifier=line.CODE_BRICK ON CREATE SET s.description=line.SOUSBRICK ON CREATE SET s.zip=line.SOUSBRICK ON CREATE SET s.id = toString(id(s)) RETURN s',
  'RETURN sec AS s',
  {sec: sec, line: line}) YIELD value
WITH value.s AS s,line,c,r
SET s.identifier=line.CODE_SBRICK 
SET s.region=line.TERRITOIRE 
SET s.regionIdentifier=line.CODE_TER 
SET s.city=line.BRICK 
SET s.cityIdentifier=line.CODE_BRICK 
SET s.description=line.SOUSBRICK 
SET s.zip=line.SOUSBRICK 
SET s.sectorName = line.SOUSBRICK   
WITH s,c,r,line
MATCH (s {identifier:line.CODE_SBRICK}),(r{identifier:line.CODE_TER}) 
MERGE (s)-[:IS_A_SECTOR_BELONGING_TO_THAT_REGION]->(r) 
WITH s,c,r,line
MATCH (s {identifier:line.CODE_SBRICK}),(c{identifier:line.CODE_BRICK})
MERGE (s)-[:IS_A_SECTOR_BELONGING_TO_THAT_CITY]->(c)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be using a neo4j version prior to 3.2, when [the rule planner was removed](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/cypher-query-options/#cypher-planner).

You can either upgrade to a more recent version of neo4j, or tell Cypher to use the cost planner by starting out your query with this clause:

```
CYPHER planner=cost
```

[UPDATED]

The error message that you are getting may be misleading.

Since the [CREATE UNIQUE](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/create-unique/#query-create-unique) clause is no longer supported in neo4j 3.2+, try changing all your `CREATE UNIQUE` clauses to use [MERGE](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/merge/#query-merge) instead. The relevant clauses are already structured such that only one thing (the relationship) may need to be created, so this should be safe to do.

If this solves your issue, you should create a new [neo4j issue](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues) about the misleading error message.

Comment: Actualy I'm using 3.1.4 version. I tried to start my query by CYPHER planner=cost but the same error still araised. I ll try the first option as you told me to upgrade my neo4j version. And I give feedback here. Many thanks cybersam.

Comment: Make sure to use the right APOC version with whatever Neo4j version you upgrade to. See the compatibility matrix on the APOC docs page.

Comment: Thank you  InverseFalcon to notify me about   APOC version. I'll do to ensure that version of the  APOC version match the new version of my upgraded Neo4j.

Comment: I upgraded my neo4j server to 3.4.0 and via browser http://localhost:7474/db/manage/server/version       I got  {
  "edition" : "community",
  "version" : "3.4.0"
}       and I'm using  apoc-3.4.0.1-all.jar in plugins  but I still have the same error     Neo.DatabaseError.Statement.ExecutionFailed RULE planner does not support calling procedures

Comment: Did you also specify `CYPHER planner=cost` to see if that helps?

Comment: I think this question is done. Please cybersam could you please help me on focusing more on that question Thank you very much .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50497811/how-to-make-the-cypher-request-to-handle-those-both-cases-without-duplicating-no

Comment: Also please cybersam see the update to my  current question.

Comment: what i am doing is as below. 1st apoc.do.when happily consumes line variable,  but 
 when the cypher reach (WITH value.r AS r, line )  I got breaking code with error Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Variable line not defined

Comment: You need to pass `line` as a parameter. Right now, you are passing an empty map, `{}`. Try passing `{line: line}`.

Comment: cyberSam Thank you very much I've put the final update on my question so this question is done by your correct answer Thank you very much.